# Date não atualiza o horario?

Tags: javascript, angular-7

Estou em um projeto no angular 7 que preciso apresentar na tela A hora, já utilizei o `Date'shortTime` e ele não atualiza o horario, alguma sugestão?

HTML

```
 <h3>{{ today | date:'shortTime' }}</h3>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 today: number = Date.now();
```

Comment: today com tipo number???

Comment: Coloca a declaração completa do componente.

Comment: obrigado, mas já consegui !! fiz uma função que faz isso vou postar

Comment: myDateTimer() {
    let d = new Date();
    let t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = t;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um

```
today = new Date()
```

E formatar isso no front com o pipe personalizado

```
{{ today | date:"dd/MM/y - hh:mm:ss" }}
```